# ASP.NET MVC - What's the best way to store objects on POST/PUT (Architecture)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture

Using asp net mvc what's the best practice for creating an action that allows to create a new project whose owner is the current logged user?

```cs
// Entities
class User {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; } 
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}

class Project {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int OwnerId;
  [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
  public User Owner? { get; set; }
}

// DTO / ModeView
class ProjectModelView {
  public string Name; 
}
```

```cs
class ProjectController : Controller {
  private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

  public ProjectController(ApplicationDbContext context) {
    _context = context;
  }

  public IActionResult Create([Bind("Name")] Project project) {
    return View();
  }

  // 1. Using the model directly
  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Create([Bind("Name")] Project project) {
    project.Owner = Session.UserId;
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
      _context.Projects.Add(project);
      _context.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction(actionName: "Index");
    }
    return View(project);
  }
  // 2. Using a dto/model view (not sure if this is considerer a model view in this case)
  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Create(ProjectModelView project) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
      _context.Projects.Add(new Project {
        OwnerId = User,
        Name = project.name
      });
      _context.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction(actionName: "Index");
    }
    return View(project);
  }
}
```

I looked up the asp .net documentation and I couldn't find a correct answer.

Which is more "ASP like" and correct option? Is there better ways to do it? Also, is the dto a ViewModel in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the `Repository/Service pattern`, togeter with `N-tier architecture`.

`N-tier architecture` looks like this

`ProjectName.Web/Server`, depending if youre making like an `mvc application`, then its `.Web`, if just a `web api`, then `.Server`
This is the main project with `controllers, automapper, views` etc.

Then three `class libraries projects`

`ProjectName.Business`, this projects is used to store most of the `helper` logic and diffrent kind of `business logic` for your application, also the `DTOs` or `ViewModels`

`ProjectName.DataAccess`, data access is the project with the direct connection to the `database`, this is the place where I use my `repository folder` with the `context` method, like `put, get, post` etc. Also the `DbContext`

`ProjectName.Models`, this project is pretty simple, it is just used for all the `entities/models` you're going to use

So how is all this connected?
The projects need `project references.`

This is how it will go
`.Models` > `.DataAccess` > `.Business` > `.Web/Server`

It goes from the bottom to the top, with the `Web/Server project` as the top since this is the `real application.`

So how do I implement the `repository pattern` into the `N-Tier architecture`?

I Create a `Repository folder` in the `.DataAccess project.`
Inside the repository create the files, for exempel if you have a model and `controller` called `EmployeeController.cs` and `Employee.cs`
Then inside the `Repository folder`, to keep it clean - create a sub folder, simply called `Employee`. Inside the `Employee folder`, create 2 files.
`EmployeeRepository.cs` and `IEmployeeRepository.cs`
Inside the `EmployeeRepository` you need a reference to `IEmployeeRepository` so your functions and methods will be available to other files.
And then just create all the context logic in the repository files.

To keep another layer between the `.Web/Server` project and the database, I Create a folder inside of the `.Business project`, called `Service`. This is the same principle as the `Repository`, create a sub folder called `Employee`, with `EmployeeService.cs` and `IEmployeeService.cs`, call all of the methods from the repository to the service, and then you call the service methods from the `IEmployeeService` to the `EmployeeController` inside of the `.Web/Server` project, using `dependency injection`.

And there you have it, complete isolation from the dbcontext in the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you this improvements, hope it helps:

1. Do not inject your db context into controllers - it is bad practise. What if your controller's methods will contain a lot of logic? And what if two controllers has similar methods with similar algorithm? You can add MediatR library with commands and handlers, and in handlers you can use you db context logic.
   Example: https://medium.com/dotnet-hub/use-mediatr-in-asp-net-or-asp-net-core-cqrs-and-mediator-in-dotnet-how-to-use-mediatr-cqrs-aspnetcore-5076e2f2880c
2. No dto is not view class, you should split domain objects and view objects, you can look to Mapper
   Example: https://code-maze.com/automapper-net-core/
3. About your question:
   Check the actor role: https://www.syncfusion.com/succinctly-free-ebooks/akka-net-succinctly/actors-in-asp-net-core

However I'm not sure that your question are still exists when you do a little refactoring from 1 and 2

Comment: Thanks for the help, the question 2 still exists however since I don't know what's the best practice to name "form" classes